# Firing an event without subscribing to it

Tags: c#, events, interface

I'm currently programming a library for simple games, mostly intended to be used by myself.
Now I've run into a problem. I have a class called "Game" which looks like this:

```
class Game
{

    private List<Entity> entities;
    private int counter;

    public Game()
    {
        entities = new List<Entity>();
        counter = 0;
    }

    public AddEntity(Entity entity_)
    {
        entities.Add(entity_);
        // problem! how to inform entity_ that it was added?

        counter++;
    }
}
```

Entity is a class which each object that acts in the game must be derived from. Its contents don't really matter. What I am looking for is a way for Game to inform the newly added entity_ class about its owner (current Game instance) and its id (which is what "counter" is for). Now I have been thinking about using an interface which would have a method "OnAdd(Game owner_, int id_)" for that as that would definitely work, but I wanted to make sure there is no preferred way over that. So that is my question:

Is there a better solution for my problem than interfaces? The Entity instance does not know what Game instance it is being added to, and using methods for event-like purposes doesn't feel right in my eyes. I could be wrong if course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Entity` has a property of type `Game`, it's easy to solve this without even using events:

```
... code ...
entities.Add(entity_);
entity_.AddToGame(this);
... code ...
```

and then in the `AddToGame` method, you would do whatever you would do in your event handler, which now is not necessary.

Comment: Clever. +1 for the "flip" of object responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes seems correct. But need to add a difference.

Interface -      Once changes, you need to track down all implementation.

Abstract Class - Virtual functions can be declared so no need to keep track for the implementations

Comment: I'm not convinced that's a valid argument for favouring an Abstract class over an Interface

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of solutions.

You could of course call a method after the `.Add`:

```
entity_.HasBeenAdded();
```

Another solution would be to "reverse the add". Something like:

Entity class:

```
public Entity
{

    ...

    public void AddTo(IList<Entity> list)
    {
        if (list == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        list.Add(this);

        // Do some logic here, as you now know your object
        // has been added.
    }
}

...

entity_.AddTo(entities);
```